# Why do we need propertie's getter if property already does it's job in python?

Tags: python, oop, properties, getter, setter

Imagine two similar classes. First has property and getter and second one has only property. Property is doing the getter job already if we do not write getter explicitly.
So why do we need to define getter?

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self._prop = 0

    @property
    def prop(self):
        print("property accessed")
        return self._prop

    @prop.getter
    def prop(self):
        print("getter accessed")
        return self._prop


class Test2:

    def __init__(self):
        self._prop = 0

    @property
    def prop(self):
        print("property accessed")
        return self._prop


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Test() 
    print(t.prop)
    et = Test2()
    print(et.prop)

# output
# getter accessed
# 0
# property accessed
# 0
```

Comment: What source told you that defining a second getter with `@prop.getter` is necessary?

Comment: `prop.getter` would be used for modifying an existing property, which probably isn't something you need to do very often.

Comment: This may be controversial (and it's just my opinion) but getters and setters for Python classes are *almost* pointless. Unlike Java (and some other languages) the concept of a **private** instance variable doesn't exist. Thus users can access instance variables at will. Whether that's good practice or not is moot. Setters make sense when you want to validate whatever's being passed into the class but there's no getting past the fact that users can bypass this mechanism at will. There, I've said it. Standing by for the pedant onslaught

Comment: @JCaesar You're not far off. Needing them *is* rare, but one of the cool things about properties is that they have been designed to allow you to *replace* a public attribute should you find it necessary without altering the public interface of your class. As a result, you can indeed use public attributes *initially* without worrying that you are locking yourself into keeping them public for all time.

Comment: Code that already freely reads from or assigns to an attribute will still work after you replace the attribute with a property (modulo the behavior of the setter, if it exists).

Comment: So, for example, feel free to use a bare attribute for some integer value. If later you need to prohibit the ability to assign negative numbers to the attribute, replace it with a property whose setter raises a `ValueError` if the argument is negative. Existing code that conforms to the property's definition continues to work unaltered, while code that tries to assign negative numbers now fails, but *by design*.

Comment: Setters, especially, can be the first line of defence. I totally agree with that. The problem is that there's no mechanism in Python for ensuring compliance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `property` class provides two ways to configure the getter, setter, and deleter methods.

1. Passing functions as arguments when you create the property.
2. Using the property's `getter`, `setter`, and `deleter` methods, each of which returns a *new* property with the corresponding `fget`, `fset`, or `fdel` overriden.

For example, given three functions

```
def get_value(self):
    ...

def set_value(self, value):
    ...

def delete_value(self):
    ...
```

you write either

```
p1 = property(get_value, set_value, delete_value)
```

or

```
# All arguments are optional
p2 = property()
p2 = p2.getter(get_value)
p2 = p2.setter(set_value)
p2 = p2.deleter(set_value)
```

`property`, `property.getter`, `property.setter`, and `property.deleter` are all designed to allow them to be used as decorators.

```
p2 = property()

@p2.getter
def p2(self):  # get_value
   ...

@p2.setter
def p2(self, value):  # set_value
    ...

@p2.deleter
def p2(self):  # del_value
    ...
```

In ordinary usage, a hybrid approach is taken: the property is created *and* initialized with a getter in one step (the first argument is the getter to support this most common use-case of a read-only property), an optional setter and deleter provided when necessary.

```
@property
def p2(self):  # get_value
    ...
```

So, the explicit use of `property.getter` is rare, but available. While all three methods could be called at any time to alter the behavior of an existing property, I don't think I've even seen them used other than for the intial configuration of a property.